# UML Sequence Diagram: Destroy an object with condition

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have a case that the application will destroy an object when condition is met. If the object is not destroyed, it will be used in later part in the sequence. I was wondering how to model that in sequence diagram.

Here is a simple demo, is that a valid sequence diagram?

[image]

Comment: Good question. I would have used an `alt` fragment with two destroys. But the tool I use (EA) allows only one destroy. So I would have dragged the destroy out and put the `if not destroy` into an `opt` fragment which is basically the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not legally model it this way in UML

> **17.12.6 DestructionOccurrenceSpecification**
>   ...
>   **17.12.6.4 Constraints**
>
> no_occurrence_specifications_below
>
> No other OccurrenceSpecifications on a given Lifeline in an InteractionOperand may appear below a DestructionOccurrenceSpecification.

Which basically means that you can have the destruction occur only once. However, you can model the above like this:

[image]